# Plot XYZ Points On Raster Layer

Tags: r, colors, geospatial, r-raster

I would like to display a set of points over a raster layer, and have them colored on the same scale as the raster. I've looked through other questions but have not solved it. The point values represent concentrations at 30 stations. The raster layer displays an interpolation grid that was generated using the concentrations. In the code below, I get the output of the interpolation which covers a wider area than I need to map. I clip it to the shp layer that I am using as the basemap. Then I map the clipped interpolation, and add the points.

I have got the map displaying the points and the raster, I am unclear on how to get the scale of the points to come out the same as the raster. I think I need to somehow extract the color gradient from the interpolation and match those up to the values in my XYZ file, but I am not exactly sure if that is the right road to go down...

My code to generate the map so far:

```
# test data for 4 stations

XYZData<- data.frame(
 X = c(577422.4, 579220.9, 580996.0, 584633.1), 
 Y = c(4210598, 4211570, 4212198, 4213455),Z = c(7.1,10.2,12,3))

library(raster)
rasterDF <- raster(idw_out) # idw_out is the output interpolation grid
newproj<-'my projection' # setting projection
a<-projectRaster(rasterDF, crs=newproj)

nfullName="./shpdata/this is my base map.shp"
nlayerName="name of my base map"
border_rev<-readOGR(dsn=nfullName,layer=nlayerName, verbose=F) # map extent
x1<-mask(a, border_rev) # clip interpolation to basemap

h<- colors(); h1<-h[10:100] # attempting to standardize colors used
p <- plot(x1, col=h1); points(XYZdata, type='p', col=h1)
```

Thanks!

Edits:
This is the summary of the raster:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 317, 425, 134725  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 250, 250  (x, y)
extent      : 540425, 646675, 4199125, 4278375  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : var1.pred 
values      : 0.1547871, 27.05386  (min, max)
```

This is link to the raster: [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Vbywb5NEAUMXh3ZkxCb0hhS2c/view?usp=sharing)

The xyz data is like this:

```
mydata <- data.frame(Longitude = c(577422.442467061, 579220.875124347, 
+ 580995.982508038, 584633.125414608, 585696.32284728, 589533.313960728, 
+ 587475.548155474, 582963.372460121, 578940.888532248, 582075.111557177 
+ ), Latitude = c(4210598.27557511, 
+ 4211569.85438234, 4212197.61081488, 4213455.20812117, 4213299.86256043, 
+ 4213030.38550458, 4214284.20259049, 4215457.67119233, 4213298.22263535, 
+ 4217435.01191314
+ ), Result = c(7.19, 10.88, 6.59, 5.92, 4.85, 3.83, 4.57, 4.71, 
+ 5.22, 2.07))
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 3):

At first, I create a reproducible example:

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

xyz <- data.frame(x = seq(-160,160, 25), 
                  y = seq(-40, 20, 5), 
                  z = rnorm(13)
)
rasterDF <- raster(ncol = 100, nrow = 50)
rasterDF[] <- rnorm(ncell(rasterDF))
```

Then, you have to convert the xyz data to a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` (and eventually `spTransform` them to your `'my projection'`):

```
xyzSP <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = xyz[,1:2], 
                                data = xyz, 
                                proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
```

Afterwards, the data of the raster cells below these points is joined to the z value (just a workaround for the reproducibility of the example; your values should already be the same)

```
xyzSP$Z <- rasterDF[xyzSP,]
```

The next step is to calculate the color which will later be used within the plot. Therefore, you have to normalize the Z values with the minimum and maximum values of the `rasterDF`:

```
ncolors <- 100
xyzSP$color <- terrain.colors(ncolors)[(xyzSP$z - minValue(rasterDF))/
                                         (maxValue(rasterDF)- minValue(rasterDF)) * ncolors]
```

Afterwards you can plot the results like this and add the point plot with `plot(...., add = TRUE)`

```
plot(rasterDF, col = terrain.colors(ncolors))
plot(xyzSP, add = TRUE, bg = xyzSP$color, pch = 21, cex = 1)
```

[image: result plot]

Comment: Thanks loki. Makes perfect sense. However, this does not work with my actual raster file, not sure why. I get this error when I am normalizing the z values with the rasterDF (x1 in my case): Error in terrain.colors(ncolors)[(xyzSP$Result - minValue(x1))/(maxValue(x1) -  : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Comment: can you provide your data (or a sample of it), in order to create a reproducible example?

Comment: @ loki. I edited above with as much as information as I could about the data. I am not sure how to post an example of the raster as its large.

Comment: @user1868064, the summary of the RasterLayer does not do it. Therefore you perhaps think about how to provide the data (or if not shareable, try to create an example which leads to this error)